# Uploading large image files and video to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, python, video, google-cloud-storage, uploading

I am using the standard python app engine environment and currently looking at how one goes about uploading multiple large media files to Google Cloud Storage (Public Readable) using App Engine or the Client directly (preferred).

I currently send a bunch of smaller images (max 20 - between 30 and 100k on average), at the same time directly via a POST to the server. These images are provided by the client and put in my projects default bucket. I handle the requests images using a separate thread and write them one at a time to the cloud and then associate them with an ndb object. This is all fine and dandy when the images are small and do not cause the request to run out of memory or invoke a DeadlineExceededError.

But what is the best approach for large image files of 20mb+ a piece or video files of up to 1GB in size? Are there efficient ways to do this from the client directly, would this be possible via the Json api ,a resumable upload, for example? If so, are there any clear examples of how to do this purely in javascript on the client? I have looked at the docs but it's not intuitively obvious at least to me.

I have been looking at the possibilities for a day or two but nothing hits you with a clear linear description or approach. I notice in the Google Docs there is a way using PHP to upload via a POST direct from the client...https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload...Is this just relevant to using PHP on app engine or is there an equivalent to createUploadUrl for python or javascript?

Anyway, I'll keep exploring but any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try [BlobStore with Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) or the [Image Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/)

Comment: I can already use the blob store, but it is not ideal. I want to upload directly from the client, to the Cloud. I'm working on something now. If it all works I'll post an answer here and create a github gist.